# Using webdriver in beautifulSoup for web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

Im trying to do the pagination webscraping using beautifulSoup, so I used the webdriver to paginate to the other pages. However I don't really sure any other way to get content from a dynamic web page using webdriver and to match with my code . Below is the full code I tried to implement the webdriver but the webdriver is not working. The web Im about to scrape is [link here][1]

```
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    page_num = (MAX_PAGE_DIG - len(str(i))) * "0" + str(i)
    raw = requests.get('').text

driver.get(raw)

raw = raw.replace("</br>", "")

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')

name = soup.find_all('div', {'class' :'cbp-vm-companytext'})
phone = [re.findall('\>.*?<',d.find('span')['data-content'])[0][1:][:-1] for d in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'cbp-vm-cta'})]
addresses = [x.text.strip().split("\r\n")[-1].strip() for x in soup.find_all("div", class_='cbp-vm-address')]

print(addresses)
print(name)

num_page_items = len(addresses)
with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(num_page_items):
        f.write(name[i].text + "," + phone[i] + "," + addresses[i] + "," +  "\n")
```

Sure, I wrongly add webdriver in the code. What should I fix so the webdriver works?

Comment: `driver.page_source`

Comment: BTW: `Selenium` has own methods to search in `HTML` and they can be more usefull if page uses `JavaScript` because you can `click()` element found with `Selenium` functions - and it can load next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Selenium` to read page then you can also use `Selenium` to search elements on page.

Some elements don't have `companytext` so if you get separatelly `companytext` and separatelly `address`/`phone` then you can create wrong pairs: `(second name, first phone, first address)`, `(third name, second phone, second address)`, etc. Better find element which groups `name`, `phone`, `address` and then search  `name`, `phone`, `address` inside this element - if it can't find name then you have to put empty name or search different element with name inside this group. I found that some elements display image with logo instead of name and they have name in `<img alt="...">`

It is not good idea to write CSV data in file using standar `write()` because `address` may have many `,` and it may create many columns. Using module `csv` it will put address in `" "` as single column.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

MAX_PAGE_NUM = 5

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Business Name", "Phone Number", "Address"])

    for page_num in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM+1):
        #page_num = '{:03}'.format(page_num)
        url = 'https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=boutique&where=selangor&screen={}'.format(page_num)
        driver.get(url)
        for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="content_listView"]//li'):
            try:
                name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="cbp-vm-companytext"]').text
            except Exception as ex:
                #print('ex:', ex)
                name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="cbp-vm-image"]/img').get_attribute('alt')

            phone = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="cbp-vm-cta"]//span[@data-original-title="Phone"]').get_attribute('data-content')
            phone = phone[:-4].split(">")[-1]

            address = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="cbp-vm-address"]').text
            address = address.split('\n')[-1]

            print(name, '|', phone, '|', address)
            csv_writer.writerow([name, phone, address])
```

---

**BTW:** you don't have to convert page number to three digits - ie. `001` - it works also with `1`. But if you want to convert then use string formatting

```
page_num = '{:03}'.format(i)
```

---

It could be done also only with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` without `Selenium`.

If you have to get HTML from `Selenium` then you have `driver.page_source` - but `driver.get()` needs `url` and then you don't need `requests` for this.

```
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

---

**EDIT:** I can get it with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` without `Selenium` only if I use `"lxml"` instead of `"html.parser"`. It seems there are some mistakes in HTML and `"html.parser"` has problem to correctly parse it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import csv
#import webbrowser

MAX_PAGE_NUM = 5

#headers = {
#  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0"
#}

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Business Name", "Phone Number", "Address"])

    for page_num in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM+1):
        #page_num = '{:03}'.format(page_num)
        url = 'https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=boutique&where=selangor&screen={}'.format(page_num)

        response = requests.get(url) #, headers=headers)
        soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
        #soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')

        #with open('temp.html', 'w') as fh:
        #    fh.write(response.text)
        #webbrowser.open('temp.html')

        #all_items = soup.find('div', {'id': 'content_listView'}).find_all('li')
        #print('len:', len(all_items))

        #for item in all_items:
        for item in soup.find('div', {'id': 'content_listView'}).find_all('li'):
            try:
                name = item.find('div', {'class': 'cbp-vm-companytext'}).text
            except Exception as ex:
                #print('ex:', ex)
                name = item.find('a', {'class': 'cbp-vm-image'}).find('img')['alt']

            phone = item.find('div', {'class': 'cbp-vm-cta'}).find('span', {'data-original-title': 'Phone'})['data-content']
            phone = phone[:-4].split(">")[-1].strip()

            address = item.find('div', {'class': 'cbp-vm-address'}).text
            address = address.split('\n')[-1].strip()

            print(name, '|', phone, '|', address)
            csv_writer.writerow([name, phone, address])
```

Comment: Do u know why I got this error when testing your code? Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities.

Comment: for which version you get it - selenium or Beautifulsoup? You would have to get which element on page gives this error and check if it has capabilities. For example some elements don't have `name` so I have to use `try/except` to catch error and search image with logo - but other values may also not exist for some items and they may need try/except. Or they can use different HTML if server generate page in different way for different devices. Or maybe it sends recaptcha.

Comment: thanks for your help. yes, i just need to deal with the except block